# Kotlin kapt: generating code through annotation processors: cannot find symbol (of generated classes) in stubs

Tags: kotlin

I have a module with annotation processor which generates quite lot of classes I use throughout the project.

I used that module in one of my projects, though it was hell to make it work properly, it works as expected - I run build, it generates classes and everything's fine.

In new project, I use the same module (just copied code), the same config etc. but if I run build, in stubs it replaces all my "to be generated classes" references as `Class<Any>`, and build fails.

Workaround is that I use `kaptKotlin` task separately:
it generates code, and than I have to build again (kapt again is run there but no errors thrown) and only than it works.

But even in `kaptKotlin` task I get lot's of `e: cannot find symbol` in generated stubs (though code is generated).

I think that while running that tasks those should be ignored or something.

How can I correct that behavior?

Or how can I make it work through single "build" task, so kapt would in stubs reference "to be generated code" correctly and not replacing with `Class<Any>`?

P.S. using latest versions of Kotlin. Tried `correctErrorTypes = true` - no success.